# Gradle tasks to deploy war file from Spring Tool Suite

Tags: spring, gradle, tomcat7

I'm using spring tool suite 3.7.0 and the gradle plugin that I installed from the STS dashboard. Somehow the gradle tasks by default were empty. I generated war file by using the "build" task but the war file is not being recognized by tomcat7 as a valid war file. Are there any other gradle tasks I need to use to generate the war file.

Also, the build.gradle file has the following plugins,

```
apply plugin: 'base'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
```

Tomcat7 shows the following log. There are no errors but the logging I've set up when the application is initialized is not shown either.

```
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/branch] has started
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/branch/WEB-INF/lib/javaee-api-6.0-6.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/branch/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:12 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/branch/WEB-INF/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Oct 28, 2015 2:14:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/branch] is completed
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. The java version I was using to build the war file was different. I'm surprised there were no errors thrown though.